# PL/SQL convert string to number Ascii

Tags: plsql, ascii

i have below script but I need to change the case to ascii
I don't get it how I need to do it.  C
Can you please help?

If someone can rewrite my code with the ascii it will be great because I don't see it :(
Thank you for your kind help.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_number(
    p_resultaat IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  -- variabelen
  v_newStudentNumber VARCHAR2(255);
  v_letter VARCHAR2(2);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..length(p_resultaat)
  LOOP
       v_letter := SUBSTR(p_resultaat, i, 1);
      v_newStudentNumber := v_newStudentNumber ||
    CASE v_letter
    WHEN 'A' THEN
      '16'
    WHEN 'B' THEN
      '17'
    WHEN 'C' THEN
      '18'
    WHEN 'D' THEN
      '19'
    WHEN 'E' THEN
      '20'
    WHEN 'F' THEN
      '21'
    WHEN 'G' THEN
      '22'
    WHEN 'H' THEN
      '23'
    WHEN 'I' THEN
      '24'
    WHEN 'J' THEN
      '25'
    WHEN 'K' THEN
      '26'
    WHEN 'L' THEN
      '27'
    WHEN 'M' THEN
      '28'
    WHEN 'N' THEN
      '29'
    WHEN 'O' THEN
      '30'
    WHEN 'P' THEN
      '31'
    WHEN 'Q' THEN
      '32'
    WHEN 'R' THEN
      '33'
    WHEN 'S' THEN
      '34'
    WHEN 'T' THEN
      '35'
    WHEN 'U' THEN
      '36'
    WHEN 'V' THEN
      '37'
    WHEN 'W' THEN
      '38'
    WHEN 'X' THEN
      '39'
    WHEN 'Y' THEN
      '40'
    WHEN 'Z' THEN
      '41'
        ELSE
      v_letter
    END;
  END LOOP;
RETURN v_newStudentNumber;
END convert_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve by  `select ASCII('a') from dual;`

Try this code:-

```
create or replace
FUNCTION convert_number(
    p_resultaat IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  -- variabelen
  v_newStudentNumber VARCHAR2(255);
  v_letter VARCHAR2(2);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..length(p_resultaat)
  LOOP
       V_Letter := Substr(P_Resultaat, I, 1);
      V_Newstudentnumber := V_Newstudentnumber ||
      ascii(v_letter);

    --  END;
  END LOOP;
Return V_Newstudentnumber;
END convert_number;
```

Comment: This is the solution.  Thank you very much for your great help!!